# Exporting mirrored animation

Tags: export, gltf, mirror-modifier

Animations that work in blender are lost in gltf format, presumably because the mirror modifier is no longer applied dynamically during the animation.

[image: Blender]

[image: Godot]

These are animations where I move around in the timeline, not just rotations. The obvious workaround is to just make each moving mesh its own object and manually mirror all animations, but is there a better way?